# Dowload pentaho 5.x

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have been trying to download the free(trail) version of pentaho 5.x.
Could any one provide me the link to download "biserver-ee-5.x-dist.zip".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the trial download at http://pentaho.com/download

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that downloads list I am finding .exe files for windows and .bin files for linux. But I need to download .zip file (biserver-ee-5.x-dist.zip) for linux.
COuld you please help me here...
This would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

Archive mode installation files can be accessible only to license purchased users. Download biserver-ee-5.x-dist.zip from Pentaho customer portal with account credentials here: https://support.pentaho.com/forums/20413716-Downloads
Source: http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/11/install-pentaho-bi-server-5-enterprise.html

EDIT: you need to pentaho customer support portal credentials to get biserver-ee-5.x-dist.zip. It is not available to open world.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pentaho community edition at [pentaho community](http://community.pentaho.com/)

Comment: is pentaho community edition free for everyone? How much is it different from biserver-ee edition? I am trying to configure the community edition, but its not working for me.